# Check if element has been clicked or changed

Tags: jquery

I have some what of a stupid question and I think I already know the answer but I would Like to find out from someone with more jquery knowledge than I have.
I have a drop down list and I would like to know if I can check to see if the ddl has been clicked or changed. Example

```
If($('#ddl').click() || $('#ddl').on('change'){
    //do something.
}
```

Comment: set a global flag to false, and inside both of the event handlers set it to true

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can bind a click and change event handler to the element and set a flag:

```
$('#ddl').on('click change', function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

// later
if ($('#ddl').data('clicked')) {
   // ...
}
```

Of course if you want to perform an action when the element is clicked or changed, put that code directly in the event handler. You don't need a flag in that case.

Answer (score 2):

This provides good reference on how to write a function to capture the change - http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$('#ddl').change(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Reference has lots of helpful tips. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can just do this:**

```js
$("#Element").click(function () {
  alert('This element has been clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Element">
  Click me and test if it works
</div>
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)