# Javascript Statement if div is clicked and has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

How is it possible to ask in Javascript if a div has a class and is clicked?

I though about this, but it doesnt work properly

```
if($('div').hasClass('box_shadow') && ($('div').click)) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: The question showed as the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471582/check-if-element-has-been-clicked-or-changed) doesn't seem to be a duplicate, but another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by JavaScript you mean jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$('div.box_shadow').click(function() {
// DO SOMETHING
});
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the trick